# Springboot What am I supposed to do about shut down Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I started a spring-boot application，then I edited the server port and restarted, then I used the old port and address to access, it succeeded but it was not what I wanted！

Comment: How do you change the port? Via applicaiton.properties/yml?

Comment: You should provide your configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change just service port and restart you can access both of old and new service ports but if you restart Eureka Server port registration would be change immediatly and you can not access old one.

Comment: thanks! Understand something now! I should learn a lot of things ！